# writing exception to parcel exception while updating contact name in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, calllog

I need to update a column (cached_name) of  table callog.calls in sql lite database in android.what I can't figure out is how to use update statement.I am unable to find anything regarding update command using cursor.kindly help.thanks in advance.

```
 //number1 is the phone number against which I need to run update query in db.
 //name is the string which I used to insert against number1..              

      String name=edittext.gettext().tostring();           
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
        Cursor cur = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
        ContentValues value=new ContentValues();

        value.put("CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME",name);

        cur.moveToFirst();  
        while(!cur.isLast())
        {                   
              String number=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));                    
              if((number.equals(number1)==true)
              {  
                    try{                   
                         cr.update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,value,CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME+"=?",null);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                         System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()); 
                    }
             }//if  
             cur.moveToNext();   
        }//while
```

Comment: I can't even understand what you are trying to do here! Why don't you make a query using number1 as a parameter to begin with? Or even directly the update?

Comment: see the edited version.I am using name there.

Comment: so basically, you want to update a call log display name for a given phone number? you don't need your cursor nor your first query. Figure out what is the selection part of your update, then figure out the setting part, then put it together in one update that represent something like "update table set value=name where phone=number"

Comment: I think I am doing kind of same.I have name which I want to insert,in where clause I have column name.please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.I am not just able to figure out what error I am making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the only line you actually need is the update :

```
String name = edittext.getText().toString();
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 

ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
// Note that there is no "" here. The value is a constant
value.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, name);

cr.update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+"=?",
    new String[] { number1 });
```

This is equivalent to this raw SQL query:

```
UPDATE call_log SET cached_name = name WHERE number = number1;
```

There is no need for iterating over all the calls, that's what the where clause is for.

Also,

```
while(!cur.isLast())
```

prevents you from actually reading the last matching value. Don't do that. Use

```
while (cur.moveToNext())
```

when you need to iterate over a cursor (which you don't, here)

I strongly suggest you take a look at how cursors work, as well as how sql works.

(Also, out of curiosity, why do you need to modify the callLog table?)

Comment: thanks a tonne,and yeah the ans for your question is, in my application I am getting the recent list of phone in my list view.what I  wanted is to add the number to the contacts which are not stored in phone and get the refreshed list back in my list view,but could not able to  because callog.calls table doesn't get updated automatically as soon as contact get stored in phone.I had to go to recent list of phone manually,because entries in callog table get updated only after they get views and then only I was able to get my refreshed list.so it was necessary to update the list programatically.

Comment: .see this[ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828930/how-to-force-refresh-on-calllog-calls-cached-name-column],                    exactly what I needed but the answer was not clear.any ways thanks a lot.